# How to submit PHP form if jquery validation is successful

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I am pretty familiar with jquery, but a novice at php, so excuse me if this is very simple.

I had a programmer develop a form that submits data into a database, but he did not program in any validation and the page bombs with minor errors.  I am going to do the validation with jquery, but need to know how to not allow the php form to post until after the validation has been complete.

Below is the jquery base that I'll be using, obviously minus all of the details.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var isValid = true;

$('.submit').click(function(event){
    memberValidation(); 
});

var memberValidation = function () {
    //Do validation

    if(isValid) {
        // Post form via .php   
    }
};
```

});

Here is the .php submit button:

```
<input type="image" src="images/signmeup.png" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Checkout" />
```

Could you please let me know what changes I would need to make to accomplish this?

Comment: First of all you should know that javascript (JQuery) validation is just "visual" - you can add it to provide a visual feedback to the user if a field is incorrectly filled, but it won't stop anyone from inserting malicious data into the database. You should always validate the data on the server side.

Comment: You can always use jQuery validation plugin, it'll make things easier for you, besides it has good examples in the documentation page, it'll help you start out with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up jQuery `.submit()` for submitting a form. You can find it in the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/submit/). You give the form an ID and use the function call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.submit').click(function(event){
    return memberValidation(); 
});

var memberValidation = function () {
    //Do validation
    if something is invalid
    return false;

    if(isValid) {
        // Post form via .php   
        return true;
    }
};
```

so if there is incorrect, it will return false and your form will not get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the answer here is to do validation on the server-side in addition to the client-side.  Client-side form checking cannot be relied upon as I could simply turn JavaScript off and completely bypass your validation.

If you really want to make sure your data is valid it must be done on the server-side, the client has too much control of their side to rely on for validation.

Comment: I would agree, but with this site we are requiring javascript.

Comment: @JonHarding If you are going to require JavaScript then your site should be setup so that if you don't have JavaScript enabled you don't see anything and never have the option to submit anything.  I don't necessarily agree that this a good approach but you can't "require" JavaScript short of making sections of your site that rely on JavaScript to simply not appear at all.

Comment: That being said, I would **still** validate on the server-side.  Never only validate on the client-side.

Comment: @Charles, yes this page will not show the form unless the user turns javascript on.  This is a very narrow audience in a common networking group. I agree this isn't the best approach. But like I said in my post, I'm not a .php developer, so I'm doing what I can.